# Configure service reference URL value from database

Tags: .net, wcf, configure, endpoint, service-reference

I am referencing a WCF service, and this is the config I have in my Web.config:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IService" />
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="http://tempserver/Service/v1/Service.svc"
        binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IService"
        contract="UserService.IService" name="BasicHttpBinding_IService" />
    </client>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

My question is: Is there a way to configure Endpoint address in the database?
Can I store - "http://tempserver/Service/v1/Service.svc" in database?

Comment: Can you store it in the database?  Sure.  You'll need to read it from the database and then configure the URL in your code, but it can be done.

Comment: When I do the below, I still get error for not specifying in the config:String baseAddress = "URLfromDB";
            BasicHttpBinding binding = new BasicHttpBinding();
            using (ServiceHost host = new ServiceHost(typeof(ServiceClient)))
            {
                host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(OktaService), binding, baseAddress);
            }

Comment: You can't specify it in the config.  You need to load it from the database and configure it in the code.

Answer (score 0):

In the class where you have written code to host your service, you can do the below configuration.

```
//Base Address for StudentService
        Uri httpBaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:0000/Service1");
        //Instantiate ServiceHost
        ServiceHost svcHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(Service1), httpBaseAddress);
        //Add Endpoint to Host
        svcHost.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IService1), new WSHttpBinding(), "");
        //Open
        svcHost.Open();
```

where the uri is hard coded in the code you can pull this value from DB.